# ViewPager not showing the right page

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to implement a ViewPager without using Fragments. Let's say, I have an unspecific amount of data stored inside some kind of database which is mapped to specific days. What I am trying to do is to display the data for a specific day on ViewPager pages.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dataList = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.dataList);
    dataList.setAdapter(new DataListSlidePagerAdapter());
    dataList.setCurrentItem(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2);
}

private class DataListSlidePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    int lastPosition;

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        if (position > lastPosition) {
            GregorianCalendar today = Settings.getCurrentDay();
            today.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
            Settings.loadData();
        }
        else if (position < lastPosition) {
            GregorianCalendar today = Settings.getCurrentDay();
            today.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, -1);
            Settings.loadData();
        }
        lastPosition = position;

        LinearLayout v = createDataList(Settings.getTodaysData());
        collection.addView(v);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((LinearLayout) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

This actually almost works, but unfortunately, the data for the current day is never shown on the current page, but rather on the next or previous page. My guess would be, that this is because `instantiateItem` does not necessarily build the view of the current page, but rather of some page which is probably needed to be shown next. `createListData()`, however, always creates the view of the current day.

Any idea how to fix this and to display the right data on the right pages? You can assume, that there are also functions like `Settings.getTomorrowsData()` and `Settings.getYesterdaysData()`.

Comment: use viewpager listener

Comment: @user1684030 Is there any reason you don't want to use `Fragment`s?

Comment: @iRuth: Actually I was too lazy to create new Fragment Classes, but apart from this: If I was using Fragments and getItem, how would I know, if I need to select the next or previous day? There is no position index or something.

Comment: @Surender Kumar: How is ViewPager Listener supposed to help me here?